# Typescript with Rx - count() function not found exception

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, typescript1.6

I'm working in Typescript, writing an Angular2 application using Reactive.  I'm not sure why but when I try to call `.count()` on an Rx observable I get the exception 'count is not a function'.  The intellisense shows that `.count()` is a function and looking at the Rx source, I see the function.  Below is some code that throws the exception:

```
myFunction(): void {
        console.log('made it');
        var x: Rx.Subject<number> = new Rx.Subject<number>();
        //var t = x.count();  //throws here
        var y = x.asObservable();
        var source = y.count(); //throws here
    }
```

> TypeError: y.count is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you try

```
var t = (<any>x).count();
```

?

My guess is that TypeScript [definition files](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/rx) for Reactive (v2.5.3) lack behind [official distribution](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/releases) (v4.0.6).

Comment: I didn't include the rx.all.js file in the system.config script.  Added it and all is fixed.